# Adding a Child in Parent View CakePHP

Tags: php, templates, cakephp

I am trying to add a child in a parent view in CakePHP.
Meaning, I have a Lesson I want to add to a Course in the Course view.

I tried doing it via a simple form helper - adding a $course['Lesson']:

```
<div class="lessons form">
<?php echo $this->Form->create($course['Lesson']); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Lesson'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('description');
        echo $this->Form->input('course_id', array(
            'value'=>$course['Course']['id']
            ));
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```

But that doesn't seem to do it.

Am I missing something in the Controller/Model?

Comment: $this->Form->create(// here is model name not an array //)

Comment: @IsaacRajaei Cake will recognize the reference even though I'm not in a Lesson view?

Comment: @IsaacRajaei 'course_id' is not populating correctly. It's giving me an empty dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

let's think course controller

//course controller

```
public function add_lesson() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Lesson->create();
            if ($this->Lesson->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Lesson has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Lesson could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }

    $this->set('courses', $this->Course->find('list'));
}
```

//add_Lesson View

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('Lesson', array('url' => array('controller'=>'courses', 'action'=>'add_lesson')) ); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Lesson'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('name');
        echo $this->Form->input('description');
        echo $this->Form->input('course_id');
    ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

Comment: Is that the Course view?

Comment: I am trying to create a new lesson in a course view. (Course HasMany Lesson)

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to add a Lesson that belongs to the Course who's view I'm in. Meaning Lesson belongsto Course I'm in course view - and trying to add a Lesson to it. Your solution doesn't address that issue.

Comment: it doesn't matter my friend you can do this in any page. You want to add data in DB - each Lesson should have an course_id That's all.

Comment: I understand that - but wouldn't this mean that I would have to be in /courses/addlesson or /courses/add_lesson? The whole idea is to have the form on courses/view/1 and submit a lesson that has course_id 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Course controller you can save your data like this:

```
$this->Course->Lesson->save($this->request->data);
```

in this case you will need to make sure after submitting your form your data is structure as below:

```
array(
      'Course' => array(
                        'id' => 1
                       ),
       'Lesson' => array(
                        'name' => 'name'
                        'description' => 'balbalbala'
                        'course_id' => 1
                       ),
);
```